# Handle Change the object in formik. using setFieldValue

Tags: reactjs, formik

how can we setFieldValue to that object.
food:{ veg:{ name:'', price:''}, non_veg:{ name:'', price:'' } }.
if food object is dynamic can be anything like,( sauce, chocolate, veg, non_veg, and so on). how can we handle change object like this

Answer (score 0):

```
const [food,setFieldValue] = useState({ veg:{ name:, price: }, non_veg:{ name:, price: }})

// key = sauce 
// value = anything you want
setFieldValue({
  ...food,
  // the `key` is dynamic
  [key]:value
})
```

Comment: const onFormChange = e => { 
let {value, id} = e.target;
setFieldValue({...food,[id]:value})
}
{Object.keys(food).map((key)=> {return (<>
    <div className="col-sm-6" key={key}>
           <TextField name="name"  id={key}
                             label={ `Food ${key}` }
                              onChange={onFormChange}
                              value={food[key].name}
                       />
        </div>
                        </>)
                    })}
)

Comment: actually  `e.target` not exist `id`, so it's not work

Comment: `const onFormChange =(e, id) => { let {value} = e.target; setFieldValue({...food,[id]:value}) }`